# How can I get the marquee tool in Photoshop to accurately snap to a grid?

Tags: marquee-tool

Currently I am working with a 128 x 128 image in Photoshop. I have grid lines dividing it into 9 sub-sections. When I use the marquee tool to select one of theses subsections it refuses to snap to the grid lines even though it is set to snap to them. I have also tried using guides with the same result. I have also tried setting the exact size of the box I am trying to select and I am still unable to change the result.[image]

Answer (score 2):

128/9 = 14,222... That's not an integer. If you mean 3 x 3 subsections, then neither 128/3 isn't an integer. Snapping can happen only at pixel boundaries. Try size 126 x 126 or 129 x 129.